# pandas apply by data type

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make **"MONTH == 6 & GRADE == 'A'"** like this.
but my code's result is **"MONTH == '6' & GRADE == 'A'"**

(single quote only string column)

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'MONTH' : [6, 6, 7, 7], 
'GRADE' :['A','B','C','D']})
```

My writing code is

```
test.apply(lambda x: test.columns.values + " == '" + x.map(str) + "'", axis=1).apply(lambda x: ' & '.join(x), axis=1)
```

I want to make this result

```
'MONTH == 6 & GRADE == 'A''
'MONTH == 6 & GRADE == 'B''
'MONTH == 7 & GRADE == 'C''
'MONTH == 7 & GRADE == 'D''
```

Comment: So you want with singles quotes, instead of double quotes? If that is the case you will have to escape the inner single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want keeping everything in dataframes

```
test.apply(lambda x: x.axes[0][1] + " == " + str(x.values[1])  + " & " + x.axes[0][0] + " == '" + x.values[0] + "'", axis=1)
```

to check if the value is a string or int in deciding whether it gets wrapped in quotes or not you would need to add an if statement in there somewhere.

I tried while breaking out the function passed to apply and this kinda worked with varying columns and such but it does add extra spaces and such.

```
def quotes(x):
    a = ""
    cols = x.axes[0]
    vals = x.values
    for i, col in enumerate(cols):
        if a == "":
            if type(vals[i]) == str:
                a = a + col + " == '" + vals[i] + "' "
            else:
                a = a + col + " == " + str(vals[i]) + " "
        else:
            if type(vals[i]) == str:
                a = a + " & " + col + " == '" + vals[i] + "' "
            else:
                a = a +  " & " + col + " == " + str(vals[i]) + " "
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list comprehension with `repr` for correct quotes:

```
#python 3.6+ solution with f-strings
a = [' & '.join(f"({k1} == {repr(v1)})" for k1, v1 in v.items()) 
                for k, v in test.to_dict('index').items()]


#python bellow with format
a = [' & '.join("({} == {})".format(k1, repr(v1)) for k1, v1 in v.items()) 
                for k, v in test.to_dict('index').items()]
```

---

```
print (a)

["(MONTH == 6) & (GRADE == 'A')",
 "(MONTH == 6) & (GRADE == 'B')",
 "(MONTH == 7) & (GRADE == 'C')", 
 "(MONTH == 7) & (GRADE == 'D')"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for a,row in test.iterrows():
    print("'{} == {} & {} == '{}''".format(test.columns[0],row[test.columns[0]],test.columns[1], row[test.columns[1]]))
```

[image]